# Autolayout UICollectionView iOS 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, autolayout, uicollectionviewlayout

I have a UICollectionView added to a UIView. I just want the collection view to resize with orientation change, so that it fits the superview (UIView). After I add the layout constraint the collection view is missing. I could not even get the first constraint work properly.(below)

```
NSLayoutConstraint *leftSideConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.collectionView
                                                                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                                                                                 relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                                    toItem:self.view
                                                                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                                                                                multiplier:1.0
                                                                                  constant:10.0];
```

And then I add the constraint to self.view.

What am I doing wrong? Please, help!

**Update:**
This is how it works. I am new to autolayouts. I was just trying to satisfy the constraints one by one to be sure that they all work:) Thank you

```
    NSLayoutConstraint *constraint1 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.collectionView
                                                               attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                                                               relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                  toItem:self.view
                                                               attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                                                              multiplier:1.0
                                                                constant:5.0];

NSLayoutConstraint *constraint2 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.collectionView
                                                               attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing
                                                               relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                  toItem:self.view
                                                               attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing
                                                              multiplier:1.0
                                                                constant:-5.0];

NSLayoutConstraint *constraint3 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.collectionView
                                                               attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                               relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                  toItem:self.view
                                                               attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                              multiplier:1.0
                                                                constant:-5.0];

NSLayoutConstraint *constraint4 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.collectionView
                                                               attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                               relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                  toItem:self.view
                                                               attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                              multiplier:1.0
                                                                constant:5.0];


[self.view addConstraints:@[constraint1, constraint2, constraint3, constraint4]];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't just add one constraint for view to position correctly. It needs to know it's x and y position, width and height. With this one constraint you only gave it x position. You need three more constraints eg. trailing, top and bottom or top, width, height. Basically any set of constraints that will fully describe view position, width and height.